Why do we use Euclidean path integrals?
I understand that Euclidean path integrals are supposedly easier to compute than Lorentizan path integrals, however I am not sure why that is. Is it just because we are used to Euclidean-signature integrals so we just figured out how to compute those, or is there another fundamental reason why Lorentzian PI’s are harder to compute? I am especially interested in this question in the framework of quantum gravity where we have quantum fields and a metric, if that makes a difference.

Normally (although it doesn't absolutely have to be that way), Lorentzian path integrals are defined as continuations (although not true analytic continuations) of Euclidean path integrals.

Isn’t it because the Euclidean integrals are convergent and the Lorentzian ones oscillatory?

The Euclidean one can be defined in terms of a true measure in some space of distributions, while the Lorentzian one cannot. So one often takes the definition of the theory in Euclidean signature as the starting point and then analitically continues the correlators.

It was Mark Kac who made the Euclidean path integral mathematically fully rigorous by introducing a Wiener process. However, Feynman did not like that. See this post.
